# "uninitialized constant AdminUser" when deploying Activeadmin on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activeadmin

I am still new to Ruby and I have been trying to deploy my App to heroku with ActiveAdmin.

After pushing my code to heroku I try to run

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

And I get the following error

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant AdminUser
```

That is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'json'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

gem 'pg', '0.14.1'

gem 'sass-rails'
gem "activeadmin"
gem "meta_search", '>= 1.1.0.pre'
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, there is a possible error in Rails 3.2 and ActiveAdmin: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/891